# What is the correct way to export a constant in ES6?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm trying to break my entry file into components but I'm not sure how to make the constant available to the import. This is what I've tried so far and both seem to work:

```
export const ConnectedRange = connectRange(Range);

exports.ConnectedRange = connectRange(Range);
```

I've seen the latter used in some npm packages but sure what to use?

Thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`export const ConnectedRange = connectRange(Range);`

Is the ES modules syntax.

`exports.ConnectedRange = connectRange(Range);`

Is the commonJS syntax.

I would recommend using the ES modules syntax, and compiling to common JS if the environment you run your code on does not support ES modules.

Answer (score 51):

As you pointed ES6 modules

```
export const CONNECT_RANGE = connectRange(Range);
```

And when you want to consume it

```
import { CONNECT_RANGE } from './myModule';
```

Answer (score 6):

With considering all the above answers,
you can also export your constant as well as a module in ES6:

```
module.exports = yourConstant;
```

and call it from your file:

**import yourConstant** (*JavaScript*)

**require yourConstant** (*Node JS*)