# Exporting variables from another file to class in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to use exported constant variables in my class. Now it's look like this:

```js
//constants.js
export const GRAVITY = 10;


//circle.js
import * as constants from './constants'

export default class Circle {
  constructor () { 
    //...
  }

  foo () {
    console.log(constants.GRAVITY);
  }
}
```

Consol shows me undefined. How can I get access to this exported constant variable in my class ? Any ideas?

Comment: FYI, didn't downvote, but I'm guessing the downvote is because this example as-is doesn't reproduce the problem you're describing.

Comment: Sounds like you've maybe got a dependency cycle? Does your `constants.js` file happen to import `circle.js` and create a Circle somehow?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43937561/what-is-the-correct-way-to-export-a-constant-in-es6

Comment: Yes, I have another file where I creating `const circle = new Circle()` and there is the same constants import  `import * as constants from './constants'`

Comment: To me, it sounds like your `constants.js` file is importing something that calls `new Circle().foo()` before the `const GRAVITY = 10;` has actually executed.