# Correct syntax to import constants in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Given the following modules, how do I import the constants module and avoid having the default property included:

```
// constants.es6
export default {
    foo: 'foo',
    bar: 'bar'
}

// anotherModule.es6
import * as constants from './constants';
```

results in `constants.default.foo`

I can't seem to get the syntax correct to end up with `constants.foo`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43937561/what-is-the-correct-way-to-export-a-constant-in-es6

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You shouldn't use an object for defining constants. Calling code is free to do `constants.foo = 42;` and change the value.

Use

```
export const foo = 'foo';
export const bar = 'bar';
```

instead.

Then the import statement you have, `import * as constants from './constants';`, will work as well.

---

If you don't want to change the way you define the constants, then your question is rather *"how do I import a default export"*, which is answered in these questions:

- [When should I use curly braces for ES6 import?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36795819/218196)
- [What is "export default" in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21117160/218196)

Comment: Of course you will still have the same problem if you are exporting an object. In general you can prevent callsites from mutating an object value by calling `Object.freeze` (recursively if needed), but on the top level at least, I'd advice for using named exports. The other advantages are: Better support in build tools because they can statically analyze exports, and modules can only import what they need.

Answer (score 11):

```
import constants from './constants'

console.log(constants.foo, constants.bar)
```

If you would like to import the constants directly from `./constants`

```
constants.js:
export const foo = 'foo'
export const bar = 'bar'

anotherModule.js:
import {foo, bar} from './constants'

console.log(foo,bar)
```

Comment: import constants from './constants'  doesn't seem to import as expected. seems to need the * - import * as constants from './constants'

Answer (score 1):

```
export default {
foo: 'foo',
bar: 'bar'
}

// anotherModule.es6
import const from './constants';

Then 
const.foo
```

Comment: Can you provide some explanation, it will be good for understanding

Comment: if you use * sign it try to import every things and put in an object  to handle imported things. with this approach you do not need to use * and there is no need to an extra object to handle imported things. so you can use const.foo instead of constants.default.foo